# Triangulation of a matrix and the eigenvalues, right?

Tags: linear-algebra

> Find the characteristic polynomial,eigenvalues, and bases for the eigenspaces of the following matrices.
>
> $\begin{bmatrix}4&0&1\\-2&1&0\\-2&0&1\end{bmatrix}$

We know that $\det(tI-A)=0$, if A is a matrix.

$A=\begin{bmatrix}4&0&1\\-2&1&0\\-2&0&1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}6&0&0\\-2&1&0\\-2&0&1\end{bmatrix}$ by subtracting the last row to the first.

Since we are dealing with a triangular matrix

$tI-A=\begin{bmatrix}t-6&0&0\\-2&t-1&0\\-2&0&t-1\end{bmatrix}$

$\det(tI-A)=(t-6)(t-1)(t-1)$

According to the Solution of ***Solution Manual for Lang´s Linear Algebra, Rami Shakarchi:***

we have

> $\det(tI-A)=(t-4)(t-1)^2+2(t-1)=(t-1)[t^2-5t+6t]$
>
> so the eigenvalues are $1,2$ and $3$.

**Question:**

Assuming that the solution is right. What am I doing wrong? Cannot I use the triangulation of a matrix? Is it right?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The eigenvalues of a matrix are not invariant under elementary row operations. They are however invariant under similarity transformation.

Comment: Could you provide a proof of your claim please?

Comment: You have already proved yourself the first claim. For second claim, suppose $A$ and $B$ are similar matrices with $A=NBN^{-1}$. Then $|A-t I|=|NBN^{-1}-tNN^{-1}|=|N||B-tI||N^{-1}|=|B-tI|$.

Comment: How do you think about the last step $|N||B-tI||N^{-1}|=|B-tI|$?

Comment: because determinant is a multiplicative function: $|N||B-tI||N^{-1}|=|N||N^{-1}||B-tI|=|NN^{-1}||B-tI|=|B-tI|$